# How to disable jupyter notebook history

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter Notebook to code in Python 2.
I'm invoking it as:

```
c:\python27\scripts\jupyter-notebook --no-browser
```

At the same time I use IPython console, launched with:

```
c:\python27\scripts\ipython
```

The problem I have is that Jupyter history is saved and is mixed with IPython history.
I don't want Jupyter Notebook history at all **-** is there a way to disable it, while retaining IPython** history?

**Platform: win32**

Update:

I have tried to use suggested setting digest approach.
But when I enter "c.Session.digest_history_size = 0" to the config, restart notebook, write "print 'next test'" in some cell, restart separate IPython and after pressing up the first thing I get is "print 'next test'".

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this Jupyter issue on Github](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3001) for the origin of this solution.

In the [Introduction to IPython Configuration](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html) using configuration scripts located in your home directory at `~/.ipython/profile_default/` is discussed.  This is the relevant directory for the `default` profile, other similar directories appear if one creates other profiles.

Inside that directory one can include the file `ipython_config.py` which will run on every usages of IPython.  However, the file `ipython_kernel_config.py` will run upon invocation of an IPython kernel, not when invoking the IPython interpreter itself.  One can test this by doing `ipython kernel --debug`.

Jupyter notebooks use this style of kernel invocation.  Therefore including a script `ipython_kernel_config.py` in the directory `~/.ipython/profile_default/` (assuming the `default` profile) with the following lines:

```
# Configuration file for ipython-kernel.

c = get_config()

c.HistoryManager.enabled = False
```

Should disable the history manager completely when using that style of kernel invocation.  Therefore one should not populate command history from Jupyter calls.

Incidentally, the file `history.sqlite` in that same directory is the command history.  So, deleting it or moving it to a different filename will clear the command history buffer.